# Scalable thread pools with work stealing

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, concurrency, threadpool

Lately I've been studying various thread-pool architectures.  The "classic" thread pool architecture usually has N threads and a single shared task queue.  I would assume this architecture scales adequately as long as individual tasks are sufficiently large.  But for a thread pool that executes many small tasks, the single queue can become a bottleneck.

The only architecture I've found via my research that addresses this is the ["work-stealing" architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_stealing#Algorithm).  Instead of a single shared task queue, there is 1 "private" task queue for each thread.  Each worker thread executes tasks on its own private queue, and then when it has no more tasks, it starts choosing other queues at random and "stealing" their tasks.  So this ensures that all threads always have work to do as long as more tasks exist, and it also solves the single-queue bottleneck problem.

However, one issue that never seems to be mentioned is how such a work-stealing queue can ever guarantee that all CPU threads will always be utilized in the same way that a single shared queue would guarantee.  The problem is that at some point, when there is no more work to do, the thread pool has to *sleep* - i.e. it has to wait on a semaphore or condition variable until more work arrives.  Otherwise, the thread pool would endlessly consume CPU cycles even when no tasks were enqueued.  But if a work-stealing thread pool has to sleep, presumably it would need a semaphore/condition variable associated with each queue - otherwise, if it used a shared semaphore, we're back to the same bottleneck problem of a single shared queue - namely, each producer thread would need to contend with the signaling the shared semaphore/condition var.  So this indicates that a work-stealing thread pool should have one sempahore/condition-variable per queue.

But if that's the case, then there doesn't seem to be any guarantee that the thread pool can ever guarantee that all CPUs will always be utilized efficiently.  For example, suppose we have 8 threads and 8 queues.  All threads are sleeping except thread[0], which is busy executing a task.  Now, a producer thread has some bad luck and enqueues another task on queue[0].  With a shared queue, that new task would immediately be executed by an idle thread.  But with the work stealing pool, the other 7 threads would just sit there idly, because they were never notified of the new task, and have no way of knowing there is more work to do.

This leads me to believe that a "work-stealing" thread pool would scale excellently under high work loads, but under low or "medium" work loads, it can never guarantee that all threads are actually being utilized to the fullest extent possible.

So how is this problem addressed with regard to the design of work stealing thread pools?

Comment: 1) The producer could look for an empty queue before enqueuing the request. 2) pthread_cond_broadcast 3) It's not a real problem. If the system was heavily loaded, the new task in queue[0] would have to wait until thread 0 finishes.

Comment: (1) and (2) though are a lot of overhead, which reduces the overall efficiency of the thread pool under high load.  With (1) especially, under high load there would never be an empty queue, and so you would have to scan all queues, which increases the overall CPU usage even more at a time when you don't want to do that

Comment: And there you go. That's why the answer is 3. There's no point in using "work-stealing" unless the system is heavily loaded. And in that case, the queues will never fully drain. If they do, it won't be long before they start filling again. So the little bit of delay on the one unlucky task is no worse than the standard delay when a task is enqueued behind 5 other tasks.